# OpenCV detect only numbers I want

Tags: python, opencv, integer, detection

Im learning OpenCV and trying to detect numbers.
So I dont want to detect the whole text from the picture only the numbers next to the colors.
Is there a Possibility to get only these 2 numbers and these 2 as an integer so I can add them together or something.

Ive tried different things but didnt came to a solution. Would be great if someone could help me, thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: cut out these parts of the image with numbers and try using the ```tesseract``` library

Answer (score 0):

If the text does not contain any number on the top, you can do it easily without opencv.

```
import pytesseract

string = pytesseract.image_to_string('nums.png').split()
numbers = [int(char) for char in string if char.isdigit()]
print(numbers)
```

If the numbers are always on the same position, you can crop areas and then tesseract.